# Fast way to Serialize a HashMap

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

Im searching for a fast and easy way to serialize HashMaps. I know the Object(Out|In)putStreams, but as far as I know they are rather slow. I tried to use GSON, but i dont like to specify the type for deserialization (As usual, who doesnt like the type erasion).

The reasion I dont use XStream: I have several huge (250k Elements) int arrays, which i have to serialize too. And i dont want the overhead of < int>< /int> for each element.

The Hashmaps are short (100-200 Elements).

Comment: What are the types of the keys and values?

Comment: Take a look at [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)

Comment: If performance is a concern, have you thought about using a native implementation via JNI?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/kryo/ - note their benchmarks here: http://code.google.com/p/kryo/wiki/BenchmarksAndComparisons

Comment: Built in serialization is going to be much simpler and probably best until you know for a fact that the serialization time for your maps is unacceptable. Have you measured? YOu could also implement some custom serialization for just the large objects.

Comment: Thanks, i guess ill continue with the default serialization until speed becomes a concern. The main purpose of this question was to know the options ill have if i run into problems.

Comment: @Quu Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the problem is in the serialization of the keys and values.  Depending on what you have, you can write it like this

```
DataOutputStream dos = 
Map<K, V> map = 
dow.writeInt(map.size());
for(Entry<K, V> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    dos.writeXxxx(entry.getKey());
    dos.writeXxxx(entry.getValue());
}
```